# PHP file_get_contents displaying content In different language

Tags: php

Apologies for the vague title but am not sure how to better describe it and have been trying to work this out for hours. Have searched Google and can find no related answers and have also searched here with no luck - I may though be searching for the wrong thing.

This started with an issue over pulling an RSS feed from Bing - which works 
fine on other sites but on a new site that I am building it brings the 
news results back in German.

For these sites I am using Godady so copied the same script to other Godady
hosting accounts that I have and the results from the Bing RSS feed came back in English as they should. On the new account however the news
displays in German.

So after going through loads of things to eliminate what the problem may
be I decided to do a simple test using file_get_contents.

On the new hosting space with nothing else in the webspace I created a php
file with this in it:

```
 <?php
 $homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.bing.com/news/search?q=cars&form=YFNR&format=RSS');
 echo $homepage;
 ?>
```

When I ran the above on the new account it displayed the page results in German when it should be English.

I copied the same test script above to another recent Godaddy account
and it works properly and displays the results in English.

The BING URL when used in a browser displays the news in English

I have been on to Godaddy support and they have tried but I think were trying to suggest it was my script. That's why I just tried the snippet above to rule everything else out.

BTW All the hosting accounts that I am using are in the USA

So the question is what would cause a simple file_get_contents to translate the output results to a different language? Why the two different results on different accounts?

Sorry for the length of posting but hope that it explains enough - please no votes down ;-)

Comment: Do you have command line access to the server that is getting the German response? Can you execute `curl -v https://www.bing.com/news/search?q=cars&form=YFNR&format=RSS` and post the results?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - appreciated - just checking to see whether the basic Godaddy hosting has command line access.

Comment: You could also use Php's `exec ()`

Comment: Use bing API. AFAIK there's a `market` parameter what stays for language/locale.

Comment: Can't seem to get in to comman line - with exec not sure of syntax but put this in a php file: exec("curl -v https://www.bing.com/news/search?q=cars&form=YFNR&format=RSS"); and nothing appeared also used echo same result

Comment: You can either pass an $output parameter to exec() or  use system() to view the command output.

Comment: @Parris Varney - Thanks again - learnt some more stuff. Ok so did as you suggested and it displayed the content from the Bing URL on screen and again it was in German. It's just the same page as in Enlgish but in German.

Comment: The beginning of the curl output should be the request and response headers, can you post them?

Comment: @Parris Varney - Sorry don't see any headers - just the page output - this is what I have written  `exec("/usr/bin/curl -v https://www.bing.com/news/search?q=cars&form=YFNR&format=RSS", $output);
    var_dump($output); `

Comment: What are the first 5 lines to that output? I suspect your godaddy server is located in a country that Bing has deemed to be German speaking, and as a couple have commenters have pointed out, you are going to have to explicitly specify which language you want the response to be in. This would be done either with the query string, or with the request headers, or with a cookie.

Comment: @Parris Varney - just wanted to update and thank you for your assistance. In the end Godaddy insisted that it was my script even when I explained that it was only a php command. So after wasting too much time I moved it to a different host where everything is working as it should. Thanks have learnt some new stuff!

Answer (score 2):

As you may know, Bing (and pretty much all multi-language websites) use cookies or browser setting to distribute appropriate content.

What I suspect in your situation is language setting of your hosting.

You can try to change header of your script to accept content in English:

```
$opts = array(
  'method' => "GET",
  'https'=>array(
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.bing.com/news/search?q=cars&form=YFNR&format=RSS', false, $context);
```

Regards,

Comment: I thought that may be something like that but it does work fine on other godaddy accounts which threw me. I have tried yours above though and it still displays in German